# I wrote a method to count positive numbers, but how to call that in main method

Tags: java

```
public class positiveCount {
    private static int countPositive(int[] elems) {
    int positive = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
        if (elems[i] > 0){
                positive++;
        }
    }
    return positive;
}
//This gives me the number of the positive numbers.

public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
}
```

in the main method, i want to enter a list, for example {3,4,5,-2,-3,0},how to call the method positveCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main method is in the same class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    countPositive(new int[] {3,4,5,-2,-3,0});
}
```

Else (works also for case 1) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PositiveCount.countPositive(new int[] {3,4,5,-2,-3,0});
}
```

Comment: Correct! Within the same class you won't need the `className.MethodName` syntax for static methods.